# How to load number of column in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, uicollectionview

I am new to swift, I am working in `UICollectionView` I need to load Seven column in it how can do it, Also padding between each cell should be `(top:1,bottom:1,left:1,right:1)`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width / 10.2), height: CGFloat(100))
}
```

[image]

```
//UICollectionViewDatasource methods
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 31
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()


    return cell
}
```

Comment: In `numberOfItemsInSection` method replace `return 31` with `return 7`.

Comment: dharmesh Kheni - I need to load 31 cells with 7 column.

Comment: sorry I got it wrong just make it clear that you want 7 columns and every column have 31 cell?

Comment: dharmesh i have updated the question i am deigning a calender, so i need 7 column and 31 cells in one section

Comment: return cell width with `collectionView.frame.size.width / 7.0`

Comment: you can use autolayout?

Comment: ronak if i give collectionView.frame.size.width / 7.0 i am getting only 6 column

Comment: you can use autolayout?

Comment: try to use `(collectionView.frame.size.width-2) / 7.0`

Comment: Set min Spacing for cell = 0 and for lines = 0 in UI

Comment: ronak you are correct I alredy fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

**Works for both horizontal and vertical scroll directions and variable spacing**

Specify number of columns

```
let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 7
```

Configure `flowLayout` to render specified `numberOfColumns`

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let horizontalSpacing = flowLayout.scrollDirection == .vertical ? flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing : flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    let cellWidth = (view.frame.width - max(0, numberOfColumns - 1)*horizontalSpacing)/numberOfColumns
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}
```